# svcutil generating MessageContractAttribute or OperationContractAttribute for different services

Tags: wcf, svcutil.exe

I'm using svcutil to make proxy classes and I've noticed that for different services I get different results.

I'm using this svcutil command:

```
svcutil http://server/SomeService.asmx 
    /l:c# 
    /syncOnly 
    /out:C:\ISomeService
    /config:C:\ISomeService.config 
    /namespace:*,SomeServiceProxy
```

Proxy classes for first service generate code like this:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="GetFirstService", Namespace="http://othernamespace.com")]
public partial class GetFirstServiceRequest : SomeServiceProxy.ResponseInfoBase
{
    ...
}
```

And proxy classes for second service generate this:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName = "GetSecondService", WrapperNamespace = "http://somenamespace.com", IsWrapped = true)]
public partial class GetSecondServiceRequest
{
    ...
}
```

Why is one class marked with MessageContractAttribute and the other with DataContractAttribute? How does svcutil decide to use one or the other, the command is same for both services?

Comment: That is because your one service may be using DataContract while other may be using messageContract . Can you publish contract definition for both services?

Comment: @PankajKapare no sorry I can't publish definitions, I do not own those two services and can't due to nda permissons. I understand what you are saying, is there a way I could force the second to use DataContractAttribute?

Comment: You could try `/serializer:DataContractSerializer` but since svcutil tries to generate DataContracts by default I doubt that'll change the outcome. - Question is, why do you even care? (If you're concerned about ugly code, well, generated code is almost always ugly. Use a thin wrapper layer above it to hide the crap. ;)

Comment: @nodots I'm using some of those Contracts in a custom method but then I get errors like -- "The operation XYZ either has a parameter or a return type that is attributed with MessageContractAttribute. In order to represent the request message using a Message Contract..." which is working fine with the other Contracts marked as "DataContract".

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530145/message-or-a-type-that-has-messagecontractattribute-and-other-parameters-of-diff

Comment: @nodots That got me thinking, so I found that svcutil made a "wrapper" of my actual DataContractAttribute object and called it `GetSecondServiceRequest` however the actual object is `GetSecondServiceRequestInfo`. If I use this object in my custom method the proxy then compiles. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataContract format [supports only a subset of XML Schema Definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-schema-reference). So it depends on the service metadata: `svcutil` (actually [System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlImporter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.description.wsdlimporter?view=netframework-4.8.1) which is used by `svcutil`) tries to generate DataContracts by default. If it encounters a schema that cannot be represented as a DataContract, it generates a MessageContract as fallback.

Comment: I guess this would be the reason, I can't confirm this as I do not own the services but the second one does look more "complicated". This answers my question so thank you for your answer.